# How i can employ DevExpress use AngularJS

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, devexpress

i tried employ devExpress use AngularJS, i followed the next steps
1)I selected a "*Load Panel*"
[image]

2)At example-page be source code of this element i selected *AngularJS*:
[image]

3)I copied the source-code to my *progressDXAngularJS.js* file:[image]

4) I opened the *Markup* bookmark at this page and copied html-source-code of this element to *progressDXAngularJS.html* file
5) I has the next page with *Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined* - error[image]

6) I added some code to my *progressDXAngularJS.js* file:
[image]

7)I have the next page without errors
[image]
8)After Click to *Load Data* button happened nothing.
9)Ofeer me please a good tutorial how to use DevExpress and AngularJS, i googled, finded examples. tutorials just devexpress and JQuery. Thanks, for your answers.

Comment: I think you didn't add your AngularJS app and controller to your page. Usually, you need to add the ng-app directive to the html tag and add the ng-controller directive to the tag which is the container for your page. See https://angularjs.org/ under the 'Add Some Control' section

Comment: No I didn't, I added ng-app and ng-controller to my html-page, I just reboot my computer and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome, I moved my comment to answer so that you can mark this thread as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you didn't add your AngularJS app and controller to your page. Usually, you need to add the ng-app directive to the html tag and add the ng-controller directive to the tag which is the container for your page. See [angularjs.org](http://angularjs.org) under the 'Add Some Control' section.